# org.apache.jasper.JspC jar file download

Tags: java, jar

I am getting taskdef class org.apache.jasper.JspC cannot be found error. Could someone please share a link where I can download the org.apache.jasper.JspC jar file?

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jasper/6.0.32

Using Maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.32</version>
</dependency>
```

It can be downloaded from here: https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=jasper&g=org.apache.geronimo.ext.tomcat&v=6.0.29.0&downloadable=1